# Create one document from singeles documents .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to create one document that contains a few singles documents.
I wrote a function that gets from the database documents, and concatenates them.
The problem is that the function only shows me the first document.
I think maybe we should separate the documents with a page break.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this / solve the problem?

```
    ds = BL.GetDocuments() 
    If Not ds Is Nothing Then
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        context.Response.Clear()

        For index = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(index).Item(0)) Then
                bytes = CType(ds.Tables(0).Rows(index).Item(0), Byte())
            End If
            If index = 0 Then
                merged = New Byte(((bytes.Length)) - 1) {}
                bytes.CopyTo(merged, 0)
                saveArray = merged
            Else
                merged = New Byte(((bytes.Length + saveArray.Length)) - 1) {}
                saveArray.CopyTo(merged, 0)
                bytes.CopyTo(merged, saveArray.Length)
                saveArray = merged
            End If

        Next
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(merged)
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, byte concatenation will not work for you, because most documents start with some kind of header saying for example, what is the size of the document body (pages count / height and width), and all following, data outside that body, is discarded (at best - some programs might fail to open or crash). From your code, I see you are trying to merge PNG images. What you need to do is rather unpack images into pure bitmaps, then create a single bitmap out of them, and then convert it back to PNG. Be careful about compression parameters or you might loose some quality.